# How to inspect GridView CommandArgument sent between browser and server in Production

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have this Default.aspx, with one piece of it like:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate> 
        <asp:GridView ID="myGridView" runat="server" DataSourceID="SomeDataSource" 
                            AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowSorting="True" OnRowDataBound="myGridView_RowDataBound" 
                                    OnRowCommand="myGridView_RowCommand" OnDataBound="myGridView_OnDataBound">
            <Columns>
                ...
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:ImageButton ID="ActionButton" 
                            AlternateText='deduct' 
                            CommandName='deduct' 
                            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("SomeId") %>' ImageUrl="deductButton.png" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField>...</asp:BoundField>
                ...
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And the behind code is like:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    ...

    protected void myGridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName != "Sort")
        {
            // do something with e.CommandArgument.ToString()
            myGridView.DataBind();
        }
    }

}
```

I reckon there must be some communication from browser to server taking place between the user clicking the button and the method myGridView_RowCommand() running. And my interest in this matter is mainly the actual value passed for e.CommandArgument, I thought I would get some clue from the decoded ViewState, but that try was in vain.

Please note that one of the premises I put is this particular value of e.CommandArgument is only observed in production, which means I cannot simply add a breakpoint in myGridView_RowCommand() and inspect the variables.

Please let me know if you need more context to understand the question.

Thank you very much.

Comment: add a literal in the page, and render there the 'e.CommandArgument' just to see what have on it... eg: `txtLiteralControl.Text += e.CommandArgument`

Comment: @Aristos answer is the best. Or you can save it in a local file.